# How to cat file with space in filename in BASH?

Tags: bash, filenames, cat

I tried to `cat` file with name `file sth.txt`. When I write

```
cat "file sth.txt"
```

It works great.

When I save the `file sth.txt` into variable `file` and I execute

```
cat "$file"
```

System writes

```
cat: file: No such file or directory
cat: sth.txt: No such file or directory
```

I want to `cat` file with variable and have in it more than one filename. For filenames without space it works. Can anybody give me some advice?

Comment: Are you using `cat "$file"` or `cat $file`? Because the quoted version should work fine.

Comment: That can't work if I have in my variable more than one files. How can I do it?

Comment: If your variable contains more than one file name then you can't support files with spaces in the names. Don't put more than one filename in the same variable. Use an array or multiple arguments.

Comment: Exactly what command did you use to save `file sth.txt` into `$file`?

Answer (score 3):

You have to assign the variable like this:

```
file="file sth.txt"
```

or:

```
file="$1"
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure your variable contains correct data? You should escape the path in the variable as well, either with `""` or `''`, or by using `\` :

```
rr-@luna:~$ echo test > "file sth.txt"
rr-@luna:~$ var=file\ sth.txt
rr-@luna:~$ cat "$var"
test
rr-@luna:~$ var="file sth.txt"
rr-@luna:~$ cat "$var"
test
```

Version = `GNU bash, version 4.3.33(1)-release (i686-pc-cygwin)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this is the way Mac OS X's Terminal deals with such cases.

```
cat /path/to/file\ sth.txt
```

You can do the same with your script

```
sh script.sh /path/to/file\ sth.txt
```

Comment: I get the file name as argument of script. I have it in $1. 
Filename is "file sth.txt".

Answer (score 0):

Use an array:

```
# Put all your filenames in an array
arr=("file sth.txt")  # Quotes necessary
arr+=("$1")           # Quotes necessary if $1 contains whitespaces
arr+=("foo.txt") 

# Expand each element of the array as a separate argument to cat
cat "${arr[@]}"       # Quotes necessary
```

If you find yourself relying on word splitting (i.e. the fact that variables that you expand on the command line are split into to multiple arguments by the whitespaces they contain), it's often better to use an array.